# MongoDB Geographically Distributed Replica Sets, why use priority 0 for secondary DCs?

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have read the documentation provided by MongoDB here, but I fails to explain why we should set non-primary DC secondaries to priority 0. 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-architecture-geographically-distributed/

I understand that if I have a setup with two nodes in site A and 1 in site B, the node in site B can never be primary if A goes down, since it no longer has a majority. So that cannot be the reason why we set priority 0. 
The only reason I can think of is to avoid any "ties" in voting if the primary in site A goes down.

I have read this question here which is similar to mine, although the OP seems to want automatic failover to site B, which I fully understand that I can never have. ([Why do MongoDB docs recommend/insist on specific replica set priority configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060021/why-do-mongodb-docs-recommend-insist-on-specific-replica-set-priority-configurat)), but the answer just list some scenarios, I doesn't explain why (or I'm still not understanding).

Answer (score 0):

This setup is meant for disaster recovery.
In case site A goes down, failing over to site B would have the effect that the network latency between your application/customers and site B becomes too high to be acceptable or even workable.

In that case you don't want B to become primary.
You would then use the data in B to set up a new cluster on another site.

Your data is save and your downtime would be small, hence disaster recovery.

Regards
Chris

Comment: Sure, but why use priority 0? Is it just to be explicit? Since there is a minority of nodes in site B, a failover should never happen even with priority > 0 if site A goes down?

Comment: You're right about the failover but if only one of the machines in A would go down, the machine in B might be eligible for election and thus become primary, which in this case you don't want to, for the already given reasons.